# Why is my vector printing as blanks when values have been entered through a file?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to store strings from a file into a vector containing an array. The following is my way of getting information into the vector:

```
    {
string line;
int nooflines = 0;
ifstream myFile("SongListFile.txt");
while (getline(myFile, line)) {
    nooflines++;
}
song temp;
    myFile.open("SongListFile.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < nooflines; i++) {
        myFile >> temp.title;
        myFile >> temp.artist;
        myFile >> temp.genre;
        songs.push_back(temp);
    }
    myFile.close();
}
```

And this is how im trying to print this information:

```
    void SongList::ViewSongList() {
    int last_element_position = songs.size() - 1;
for (int i = last_element_position; i >= 0; i--)
{
    cout << "\"" << songs[i].title << "\" by " << songs[i].artist << " (" << songs[i].genre << ")" << endl;
}
```

Why are the strings printing as if they contain nothing? Two of the templates print when there are two lines of text, so my problem is the strings not being stored in my array.
}

Comment: Have you stepped through this code in your debugger and verified that it does what you think it does?

Comment: Why do you need to count the lines first? Just push onto the `songs` vector in the first loop.

Comment: Checking even one of the looped stream reads for `Song` that you're assuming worked would expose the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Apart that you could do the reading in one pass, as indicated in comments and other answers, the way you are "re-opening" the file is not correct. After the first pass a flag of your `ifstream` has been set when reaching the end of the file. Opening again the file (without closing) wont clear the flag.

You need either to `myFile.close()` before re-opening, or alternatively clear the flags then *seek* to the beginning:

```
myFile.clear();              // clear the flags
myFile.seekg(0, ios::beg);   // seek back to beginning for the second pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to count the number of lines in the file at all. You can do it in one pass :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Song { string title, artist, genre; };

int main() {
  ifstream myFile;
  myFile.open("songList.txt");

  string aLine;
  vector<Song> songs;
  while(getline(myFile, aLine)) {
    stringstream sin(aLine);
    Song aSong;
    sin >> aSong.title >> aSong.artist >> aSong.genre;
    songs.push_back(aSong);
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < songs.size(); i++)
   cout << "\"" << songs[i].title << "\" by " << songs[i].artist << " (" 
     << songs[i].genre << ")" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```